# My coworker and I were trying to solve a problem -- we both tried two different things at once that only worked because of the other's attempt

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms, phrase-requests

Each solution to the problem we were trying to solve would have independently failed. We were each trying many different solutions at the same time. We each happened to try a solution that worked, but only because the other had tried a complimentary solution.

Is there a word, phrase, idiom, or analogy that describes such a solution?

An example: It's like if we had a whole bunch of light switches and were flipping each of them on and off to see if it controlled the light we were trying to turn on. Unbeknownst to us, the light needed *two specific* switches to be turned on. Had we been trying independently, we'd have flipped one on, seen no reaction, then flipped it off. However, we happened to each flip one of the two correct switches at the same time, causing the light to turn on. We then each thought we had found the correct *one* switch, but in further experimentation we realized that the light had needed both of us to switch on the two switches at the same time.

It was an interesting (and probably very lucky) event. I've been trying to come up with a word or phrase to describe it, but I am only getting generalizations like it was 'serendipitous' or it was like we had built two halves of a bridge.

Comment: Consider "symbiosis" in its figurative sense of any interdependent or mutually beneficial relationship between two persons.

Comment: A symbiotic relationship wouldn't have the light switch problem but a synergistic one could.

Comment: *Complementary*

Comment: Just *synergy* - no more, no less.

Comment: You clearly need a portmanteau of *serendipity* and *synergy*. How about *synergipity*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Synergistic inadvertent catalytic relationship.**

*synergy*, noun:

> the interaction or cooperation of two or more organizations, substances, or other agents to produce a combined effect greater than the sum of their separate effects.

*inadvertent*, adjective:

> not resulting from or achieved through deliberate planning.

*catalyst*, noun

> a person or thing that precipitates an event.

All sources are from Google and the phrase appears verbatim in a [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=el_SBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=Synergistic%20inadvertent%20catalytic%20relationship.&source=bl&ots=d8-O-_VcLs&sig=edArnK8iJvV03G2JS8s1UaN2FyA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqvantwKPMAhVIGsAKHeLqDIsQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Synergistic%20inadvertent%20catalytic%20relationship.&f=false) (note however, therein *Synergistic* is a column header).

Comment: Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious!

Answer (score 0):

You could broadly call this [***teamwork***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/teamwork):

> cooperative or coordinated effort on the part of a group of persons
>   acting together as a team or in the interests of a common cause.

but a word that you used in the question (albeit misspelled)
provides a more specific description of what happened:
the other person's actions [***complemented***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/complement) yours:

> *complement*:
>   **noun**
>   1. something that completes or makes perfect
>
> **verb** (transitive)
>   12. to complete; form a complement to

or your actions and the other person's were [***complementary***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/complementary):

> 1.  Forming or serving as a complement; completing
>   2.  Offsetting mutual deficiencies or enhancing mutual strengths

Comment: Yes, the complementary we should be using here is with an E.

Answer (score -2):

["Many hands make light work."](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/many-hands-make-light-work) may be used to mean that doing a task is easier if more people do it together (e.g. you and your coworker) than if one person does it alone.

["Two heads are better than one."](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/two-heads-are-better-than-one.html) may be used to mean that, if there's a task to be done, having two people work on it together is better than one person working on it alone. (The saying has more scope -- e.g. it may be used to advise someone to get advice or an opinion from a second person.)

Comment: This does not get at what the OP is asking about

Comment: In fairness, _Many hands make light work_ is pretty funny, though.

Comment: As a reminder, Stack Exchange answers should *explain*, not merely *suggest*. How are these expressions used, and how do they fit the need expressed in the question? Can you find examples? Without such elements, for someone learning English or simply unfamiliar with the expressions, the answer is hard to distinguish from personal opinion or conjecture.